# Java Unicode to readable text conversion decoding

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, ascii

I am developing a Java application where I am consuming a web service. The web service is created using a SAP server, which encodes the data automatically in Unicode. I get a Unicode string from the web service.

"
倥䙄ㄭ㌮਍쿣ී㈊〠漠橢਍圯湩湁楳湅潣楤杮਍湥潤橢਍″‰扯൪㰊഼┊敄瑶灹⁥佐呓′†䘠湯⁴佃剕䕉⁒渠牯慭⁬慌杮䔠ൎ⼊祔数⼠潆瑮਍匯扵祴数⼠祔数റ⼊慂敳潆瑮⼠潃牵敩൲⼊慎敭⼠う㄰਍䔯据摯湩⁧′‰൒㸊ാ攊摮扯൪㐊〠漠橢਍㰼਍䰯湥瑧⁨‵‰൒㸊ാ猊牴慥൭ 䘯〰‱⸱2
"

above is the response.

I want to convert it to readable text format like String. I am using core Java.

Comment: What do you mean by "readable text format"? Unicode is already readable.

Comment: You're probably decoding it using the wrong Unicode format.  Try UTF8 or UITF16.

Comment: @casablanca:Readable english format.!!!

Comment: @dda:I didnt mean to be offensive in any way....

Comment: The way this website works is, when you ask a question, you are expected to "reward" the people who answer, and help you, by voting on the answers, and pick the best one.

Comment: Yes but i think it will be misguiding people when i accept any answer which not exactly correct..again i am not denying efforts shown by people like Bobince and Joop.....they have helped me til now....this is the way i am thinking..if you feel i am wrong then please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `byte[]` or an `InputStream` (both binary data) you can get a `String` or a `Reader` (both text) with:

```
final String encoding = "UTF-8"; // "UTF16LE" or "UTF-16BE"

byte[] b = ...;
String s = new String(b, encoding);

InputStream is = ...;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, encoding));
for (;;) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
}
```

The reverse process uses:

```
byte[] b = s.geBytes(encoding);
OutputStream os = ...;

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OuputStreamWriter(os, encoding));
writer.println(s);
```

Unicode is a numbering system for all characters. The UTF variants implement Unicode as bytes.

---

***Your problem:***

In normal ways (web service), you would already have received a `String`. You could write that string to a file using the Writer above for instance. Either to check it yourself with a **full Unicode font**, or to pass the file on for a check.

You need (?) to check, which UTF variant the text is in. For Asiatic scripts UTF-16 (little endian or big endian) are optimal. In XML it would be defined already.

---

***Addition:***

[FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) writes to a file using the default encoding (from operating system on your machine). Instead use:

```
new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("...")), "UTF-8")
```

If it is a binary PDF, as @bobince said, use just a FileOutputStream on byte[] or InputStream.

Comment: Hi Joop..thanks for answering my question...but when i write string contents received from web service to a file using fileWriter....it still gives me unicode characters with Chinese characters...can you please give any further view about this..any work around..

Comment: No problem, see Addition in my answer. I seldom use FileWriter myself, as the app then may use a different encoding on a different computer.

Comment: Hi Joop,Thanks for reply..but i have tried writing to file using FileWriter and also FileInputStream.Its not giving me corect results.And also UTF-8 encoding is not working.I will UTF-16EL encoding and let you know if i get success.

Answer (score 2):

> 倥䙄ㄭ㌮਍쿣ී㈊〠漠橢਍圯湩湁楳湅潣楤杮਍湥潤橢਍″‰扯൪㰊഼┊敄瑶灹⁥佐呓′†䘠湯⁴佃剕䕉⁒渠牯慭⁬慌杮䔠ൎ⼊祔数⼠潆瑮਍匯扵祴数⼠祔数റ⼊慂敳潆瑮⼠潃牵敩൲⼊慎敭⼠う㄰਍䔯据摯湩⁧′‰൒㸊ാ攊摮扯൪㐊〠漠橢਍㰼਍䰯湥瑧⁨‵‰൒㸊ാ猊牴慥൭ 䘯〰‱⸱2

That's a PDF file that has been interpreted as UTF-16LE.

You need to look at what component is receiving the response and how it's dealing with the input to stop it being decoded as UTF-16LE, but ultimately there isn't a 'readable' version of it as such, as it's a binary file. Extracting the document text out of a PDF file is a much bigger problem!

(Note: Unicode is a character set, UTF-16LE is an encoding of that set into bytes. Microsoft call the UTF-16LE encoding "Unicode" due to a historical accident, but that's misleading.)

Comment: Thanks for answering.Actually i am looking at server side what encoding technique is used.And yes its PDF document sent as attachement through SOAP Web Service.But still i also tried to generate PDF document using Java iText library with above response writing to file..But that also didnt work.If you still got any idea please share.Thanks and Regrads.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not a valid string. This looks like mangled UTF-16.

### UPDATE

Indeed @Bobince is right, this is a PDF file (most probably in UTF-8 / or plain ASCII) **displayed** in UTF-16. When Displayed in UTF-8 this string indeed shows PDF source code. Good catch.

Comment: Yes maybe its mangled UTF-16 string...i am taliking with people handling webservice ..but as they are sap people they dont know much about decdoing formats....still thanks for your efforts..

Comment: I put this string in a text editor, told it it was UTF-16, and asked the editor to reopen the file as UTF-8, and whoop dee dah, PDF content appears. So definitely UTF-16.

Comment: @dda when you said PDF content appeared on opening the file as UTF-8, is it normal English text? Can you please tell me what is the editor you used here?