# Java File path encoding?

Tags: java, encoding, path

I have made a simple app that asks the user for a folder name in which later will copy some files. The problem is that the folder name will contain non lating (Greek) characters. And while the folder is being created with the correct name and no errors, when I store its AbsolutePath in a String the greek characters get like this **??????**_22-03-2012. When I try to use the stored path to send the copied files I get error because java can't read the path properly!

```
package newOrderAndXCopy;

import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import initiate.*;

public class NewOrder {

private String orderPath = null;

//constructor
public NewOrder() {     

    if(newOrderName()) {

        File nO = new File(orderPath);
        nO.mkdir();

    }       

}

public boolean newOrderName() {
    boolean name = false;
    int counter = 3;
    while(counter > 0) {

        String test = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Here I ask the user to give the order name with this form -> ΠΑΡΑΛΑΒΗ ΧΧ-ΧΧ-ΧΧΧΧ (π.χ. ΠΑΡΑΛΑΒΗ 12-04-2013):");
        if(!test.matches("ΠΑΡΑΛΑΒΗ \\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}")) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong name!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            counter--;

        }
        else {
                            //replace the space with underscore
            String rep = Config.savesPath + test.replaceAll(" ", "_") + "/";

            File no = new File(rep);
            if(!no.exists()) {
                orderPath = rep;

                --> Config.orderPath = no.getAbsolutePath();  <--
                /*This part is where it gets messy. The folder is created but this value is wrong so I can't use it later!*/
                name = true;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The order folder was created!!", "Success!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                break;
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The order with this name already exists!Pick another Name!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        }

    }
    return name;
}
}
```

Comment: This may well be a display issue rather than a problem with how the data is stored in your `File` object. Can you show some code that demonstrates how you produce the file and how you print the path?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414668/java-unicode-to-readable-text-conversion-decoding).

```
String encoding = "UTF-8";
new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), encoding ))
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), encoding ))
```

The problem may lie in using a FileWriter or leaving out the encoding parameter (defaults to the platform encoding).

For reading the file you need to set the encoding in the editor right.
Or write HTML where you can indicate the charset.

Comment: No, as i said the folder is being created!The problem is that when i store its absolutePath in a String to use it as a destination path later, its stored with the non latin chars as question marks. The actual created folders name is ok though.

Comment: `String test = JOptionPane.showInputDialog` (storing in a string #1) is still okay. `Config.savesPath` is likely wrong somehow. How do you get it? If from .properties (ISO-8859-1) it should be with `\uXXXX` codes.

Comment: Config.savesPath is ok cause it consists of latin chars only. Config.targetPath is problematic and i get it by asking for the absolute path of a file.

Comment: I get `???` only when the encoding is wrong, like System.out.println to the console/IDE. So it must be the outputting code. Please show that.

Answer (score 0):

Your app needs to handle non-latin characters, so make sure the default encoding supports this.

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
```